# kscreenlocker_greet: Disable VLC controls

Tags: kde, vlc, screen-lock

When locking my screen I get the VLC controls for the actively playing video on the lock screen.

How can I disable these controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the media controls from the lock screen (in kscreenlocker version 5.11.95 or higher):

1. Open System settings.
2. Go to Workspace > Workspace Behavior > Screen Locking.
3. Click on the second tab (Appearance).
4. Remove the checkmark at "Media controls: [x] Show"

[image: screenshot: Configure Screen Locking]

(image from https://phabricator.kde.org/D9684 / https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=384264 )

Tested with the Breeze theme, kscreenlocker version 5.17.4.